# In Corona SDK, How do I get an object to keep moving while touching the background screen?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Here's the situation. I want a square object to continuously move in y-direction as long as I'm touching the screen. Based on the code, I have it should give me a continuous movement of the square object, but, only when I'm sliding with my finger on the touch screen, the object moves. I want the square object to continuously move when I'm touching the screen on the same spot.

I tried using both timer and runtime event listener to no avail. What's the fix here?

```
_W = display.contentWidth 
_H = display.contentHeight 


local background = display.newRect(0,0,_W,_H)
background.anchorX = 0
background.anchorY = 0


local squareTimer

local function squareMoveUp()
     square.y = square.y - 5
end    

local holding = 'false'
local function startMove(event)

     if event.phase == 'began' then
        --Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame',squareMoveUp)  
        squareTimer = timer.performWithDelay(200,squareMoveUp,0)

     elseif event.phase == 'ended' then
        --Runtime:removeEventListener('enterFrame',squareMoveUp)

     end
     return true
end 

background:addEventListener('touch',squareMoveUp)
```

Comment: The `background` should full screen.

Comment: It is. I just didn't include that code.

Answer (score 0):

This works just replace square with your object:

```
_W = display.contentWidth 
_H = display.contentHeight 


local background = display.newRect(0,0,_W,_H)
background.anchorX = 0
background.anchorY = 0

local square = display.newRect(200,200,_W/3,_H/3)
square:setFillColor( 1,1,0 )

local squareTimer
local touchStarted = false


local holding = 'false'
local function startMove(event)

     if event.phase == 'began' then
        --Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame',squareMoveUp)  
        squareTimer = timer.performWithDelay(200,squareMoveUp,0)
        touchStarted = true
            local function squareMoveUp( )
                square.y = square.y - 0.02
            end

        for i = 1,1000 do
          if touchStarted then 
                    squareTimer = timer.performWithDelay(200,squareMoveUp,1)
        end
    end

    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
            touchStarted = false
     end
     return true
end 

background:addEventListener('touch',startMove)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like in the below.

```
_W = display.contentWidth 
_H = display.contentHeight 


local background = display.newRect(0,0,_W,_H)
background.anchorX = 0
background.anchorY = 0

local square = display.newRect(200,200,_W/3,_H/3)
square:setFillColor( 1,1,0 )

local touchStarted = false

local function startMove(event)

        local function squareMoveUp( )
          if touchStarted then 
            square.y = square.y - 10
          end
        end
 if event.phase == 'began' then
       touchStarted = true
 elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
        touchStarted = false
 end

timer.performWithDelay(200,squareMoveUp,0)
end 

background:addEventListener('touch',startMove)
```

or you can change the code in the squareMoveUp such as: `transition.moveTo( square, { y=square.y-10, 1 } )` instead of  `square.y = square.y - 10` 
it will be more smooth.